# How two convert the following lines in matlab to c++

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I want to convert the following lines written in matlab to c++

```
      int i = 5;
      m=cos(pi*theta(i)/180.0);
      n=sin(pi*theta(i)/180.0);
```

Please Help! I am a newbie...

Comment: `int i = 5` looks like C++ to me, may be you made some typo?  You should also probably show more code so we know what `theta` is.

Comment: What does 'theta(i)' return? `i` in radians?

Comment: @Gabriel: `theta` is not a known function in maatalb. it is probably an array that is indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm not sure what the theta() function does in MATLAB, I'll make an attempt to answer your question:

The C++ library you are looking for is **math.h**
It has the sin() and cos() functions in it. List of all functions in math.h refer [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/).

Both sin() and cos() function accept one argument of type 'double', which must be in radians.

So to find the sin and cos of 30 degree (say):

```
double pi = 3.14159265;
int i = 30;
double  m, n;
m = cos(pi * i / 180);
n = sin(pi * i / 180);
```

Comment: Correction: m, n have to be doubles (double m, n;) . Otherwise, only the integer value of whatever is returned by sin, cos is stored.

Comment: there is no theta function in matlab... `theta` is probably an array here that is being indexed by `i`

Comment: in the case whee theta is an array, the code may be changed to
`m = cos( pi * theta[i] / 180 );` 
`n = sin( pi * theta[i] / 180 );`